# How to change lock screen shortcut for Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.04, lock-screen

Right now, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> locks the screen but I want to make it <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> as the shortcut, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 19):

You can do that using the keyboard settings:

1. Press the Windows key (in Linux world, more correctly called the Super key), then type `keyboard`.
2. Click on the `Keyboard` program that appears first in the list to open it.
3. From the `Shortcuts` tab, select `System` in the left pane.
4. In the right pane you can change the `Lock screen` option, just click on it and press any combination of keys that you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running KDE (or Kubuntu), you can change the shortcut to lock your desktop through the `Global Shortcuts` system settings module. This procedure has been tested in Plasma 5.10.5 and kubuntu 17.10.

1. Access the `Global Shortcuts` system settings module via `System Settings` and then click the `Shortcuts` icon in `Workspace` category; or by typing `Global Shortcuts` from the Application Menu or Application Dashboard.
2. Select `ksmserver`.
3. Select `Lock Session`
4. Switch to `Custom` and click on the gear icon to assign your own.